# how to install omnipay in laravel 5.1?

Tags: package, laravel-5.1, payment, omnipay, thephpleague

I am installing OmniPay but do not see it anywhere that classes should I put in the file app.php

Documentation only tells how to install with composer, but it shows what i have to put in the file app.php, that put classes.

https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay

```
'providers' => [
...
```

],

```
'alianses' => [
...
```

]

what should i put into providers and alianses?

Comment: Have you checked out a Laravel specific Omnipay package at all? I use this and it does the trick nicely, it is still Omnipay but comes with the service provider all ready to go; https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay

Comment: hoho thank you so much, it is the package that i need, thanks bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting my comment as an answer to wrap the question up and provide a reference for anyone who comes across it later on.

The default OmniPay package doesn't have a service provider built for Laravel, so instead we should use a Laravel specific OmniPay package to make life easier for ourselves: such as [this one](https://github.com/ignited/laravel-omnipay).